# Calling C++ template function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, templates, marshalling

I have very limited knowledge of C#. My goal is to provide a C++ dll API to my C# co-worker. The dll has to be in C++ for legacy reasons.

Question - Can a C++ template function (shown below from VS) be marshaled in C#?

```
class  __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
public: 
    template <typename T> T* getFoo(T* fooData){return fooData;};
};
```

If not, any suggestions? Should each type that is passed into the template function have their own function so C# can marshal it?

Comment: @Yochai This isn’t the same question.

Comment: @Yochai: This question isn't about porting, but interfacing.  LEO is still planning to use C++ to build the DLL.  Not even close to a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question - Can a C++ template function (shown below from VS) be marshaled in C#?

No. There is no compatible binary interface from C# to C++. You can only call exported C symbols from C#.

Theoretically, you could explicitly instantiate the templates in the C++ DLL, which will cause them to get external linkage and entries in the export symbol table. But name mangling will make the functions unusable for all practical purposes. The best way is therefore to have an intermediate C-compatible layer which calls the underlying C++ functions.

Comment: Correct, and this doesn't just affect templates, but also classes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think i'll take Rytmis idea and try to deveop an API using C++/CLI

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to write your code in [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). You can expose a managed API that can be consumed by the C# code, but still use native C++ when required.

Answer (score 1):

So after a few weeks I was able to get something running and I thought I would share it with the group. (Pardon the Pseudo code Appearance). I basically taught myself C# instead of C++/CLI.

Remember the Question - Can a C++ template function (shown below from VS) be marshaled in C#?

My work around is as followed: Make marshaled unmanaged C# calls to C++ functions that can translate calls to the template method.

Here is the Code:

```
//C++ code
//C++ Header
class  __declspec(dllexport) Foo
{
    public: 
        template <typename T> T* getFoo(T* fooData){return fooData;};
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void call_getFoo(Foo* pFoo, void* pfooData, int fooId)
{
    switch(fooId)
    {
        case(ENUM::1) : //Use an enum here for a better switch statement.       
        {   
            //Cast the void pointer to a specific type so the template knows how to use it.
            pFoo->getFoo((*TypeCast*)pfooData);
        break;
        }
    }
}

//C# Code
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    const string _dllLocation = "Foo.dll";

    [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
    static public extern void call_getFoo(IntPtr pFoo, IntPtr pfooData, int fooId);           
}

//In a C# method
...
...
//Marshal Up a C# data type to a pointer for C++.
*YOUR TYPE HERE* myType;
int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(myType);
IntPtr pfooData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(myType,pfooData,true);

//call the C++ dll
UnsafeNativeMethods.call_getFoo(pFoo, pfooData, fooId);

//Convert Ptr Back To myType
myType = (*YOUR TYPE HERE*) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pfooData, typeof(*YOUR TYPE HERE*));
...
...
```

Hope that helps!